When to use sharps or flats for chromatic alterations of scale degree ^5 and ^6
Here is a piece of music I composed with some chromatic notes which I am having difficulty notating correctly.

In bar 2 I wrote C♮ (lowered scale degree ^6). In bar 3 the same tone is written as B♯. The reason I did this was because of how these tones function. Have I used the correct accidentals?

The accidentals look fine. In bar 2 you’re using them to match the Am iv chord on beat 3. In bar 3 the B# is simply a brief ascending chromatic passing note leading to the C#.
As an aside I would like to mention there is a bit of a rub on beat 3 of bar 3 because you have the C# and D# in the melody against the A minor chord in the left hand. That may be what you are going for but I thought I’d mention it just in case.

Thanks for the reply, yes that is a bit of a rub... I didn't want an Aug 2nd but I did make another alteration which sounds good. thanks for your attention to detail.

@armani My pleasure. My first thought for that beat was to make the C# and D# both naturals like in the previous measure to match the Am chord. That would of course change the function of the B# but it could possibly be swapped out for a B natural.
